# Convert JPEG file to MPEG still frame format

Tags: mpeg

Anyone know how to convert a JPEG image to MPEG still frame format? I'd love to do it in java but a linux command line process would be ok. (I saw something on code project that does this for c sharp).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it myself but here is an overview of converting JPEG's into MPEG's. I would take a look at using FFMPEG.

Overview Link: 
http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/
FFMPEG: 
http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/